# How to style an element based on another element changes without JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have to style an input control based on the select box's class. If select box has a class "error", then I need a red border on the input control. How can I do that with SASS ?  There is no common wrap, only one thing is that the wrap of the input control (.select-input-wrap) is adjecent to select box. Here is the DOM structure.

```
<select class="form-select error"></select>
<div class="select-input-wrap">
  <input class="select-input" name="select-input" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to style a sibling element, try the below code in your SASS file.

```
$red: #f00;

.error {

  &.form-select {

    + .select-input-wrap {

      > .select-input {
        border: 1px solid $red;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In pure CSS (and so in SASS), you can target sibling elements using the `+` operator. For instance:

```
.form-select.error + .select-input-wrap input {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Related sandbox: http://www.cssdesk.com/r8Dh8

Comment: Oh yeah, no need for parent!

Answer (score 0):

If your `select` and `div` elements share a parent, you can style based on that:

```css
.parent .error + .select-input-wrap input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <select id="some-sel" class="form-select error">  </select>
  <div class="select-input-wrap">
    <input class="select-input" name="select-input" />
  </div>
  
    <select id="another-sel" class="form-select">  </select>
  <div class="select-input-wrap">
    <input class="select-input" name="select-input" />
  </div>
</div>
```

For the SASS version, just take out the extra punctuation!

Answer (score 0):

This is a css solution. Hope you can convert to sass structure.

```css
.error~.select-input-wrap input{
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-select error"></select>
<div class="select-input-wrap">
  <input class="select-input" name="select-input" />
</div>
```